# Magento 2 - Error in magento during re-indexing by CLI?

Tags: magento2, error, reindex

I am using magento 2.2.2. I am working on it last 3 months. But suddenly It giving me this error while I run command for re-indexing the site.
commend for re-indexing,

`php bin/magento cache:clean;`

`php bin/magento cache:flush;`

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex;`

Catalog Search indexer process unknown error,

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.category_ids' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`category_ids`, `e`.`sku` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `website` ON website.product_id = e.entity_id AND website.website_id = '1' WHERE (e.entity_id > 0) ORDER BY `e`.`entity_id` ASC
>    LIMIT 100

Does anyone have the solution for this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please see, category_ids is not in `catalog_product_entity`.

Comment: Yes I have also checked in database before posting, can you please help me for resolving thins issue.

Comment: First, execute `php bin/magento indexer:reset`. After that execute `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`. I hope this is work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Please set product attribute category_ids to searchable `No`.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: It is working now or not. **@bansal**

Comment: Yes it's working fine

Comment: I have already post my answer

Answer (score 1):

I have resolve my issue at my end. I make category_ids product attribute searchable no. 
It's work for me.